# JSON Formatting issue in C#

Tags: c#, json, azure, rest, json-deserialization

I understand this might be an easy thing or C# Experts but I'm kinda struggling to get values out of a Http Response using Azure Rest API.

**What I trying to do**: I have a requirement to get Azure TrafficManager **ProfileName**, **EndpointName** and **TargetName** from Azure Rest API using C#. I managed to get to the **ProfileName** but unable fetch the **Endpoint** Name and **Target** Name from the response.

Each Subscription has more than one Traffic Manager Profiles and each Profile has multiple Endpoints. So, I looped the initial ProfileName Response (1st Rest API Call) in FOR Loop which is working fine and trying to get to Endpoints and Targets out (2nd Rest API Call) in below code.

Please help me fetch Endpoints and Targets from 2nd Rest API Call.

I pasted the HTTP Response that I'm getting from 2nd Rest API Call.

**2nd Http Response which has Endpoint Name and Target Name**

```
{
"id":"\/subscriptions\/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\/resourceGroups\/MyResourceGroupName\/providers\/Microsoft.Network\/trafficManagerProfiles\/MyTrafficManagerProfileName",
"name":"MyTrafficManagerProfileName",
"type":"Microsoft.Network\/trafficManagerProfiles",
"location":"global",
"tags":{},
"properties":
    {
        "profileStatus":"Enabled",
        "trafficRoutingMethod":"Weighted",
        "dnsConfig":
            {
                "relativeName":"MyTrafficManagerProfileName",
                "fqdn":"yTafficManagerProfileName.trafficmanager.net",
                "ttl":60
            },
        "monitorConfig":
            {
                "profileMonitorStatus":"Online",
                "protocol":"HTTPS",
                "port":443,
                "path":"\/vip",
                "intervalInSeconds":30,
                "toleratedNumberOfFailures":3,
                "timeoutInSeconds":10
            },
        "endpoints":
        [
            {
                "id":"\/subscriptions\/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\/resourceGroups\/MyResourceGroupName\/providers\/Microsoft.Network\/trafficManagerProfiles\/MyTrafficManagerProfileName\/azureEndpoints\/MyEndPointName1",
                "name":"MyEndPointName1",
                "type":"Microsoft.Network\/trafficManagerProfiles\/azureEndpoints",
                "properties":
                    {
                        "endpointStatus":"Enabled",
                        "endpointMonitorStatus":"Online",
                        "targetResourceId":"\/subscriptions\/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\/resourceGroups\/MyResourceGroupName\/providers\/Microsoft.Web\/sites\/MyTrafficManagerProfileName",
                        "target":"MyTargetName1",
                        "weight":1000,
                        "priority":1,
                        "endpointLocation":"North Central US"
                    }
            },
            {
                "id":"\/subscriptions\/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\/resourceGroups\/MyResourceGroupName\/providers\/Microsoft.Network\/trafficManagerProfiles\/MyTrafficManagerProfileName\/externalEndpoints\/MyEndPointName2",
                "name":"MyEndPointName2",
                "type":"Microsoft.Network\/trafficManagerProfiles\/externalEndpoints",
                "properties":
                    {
                        "endpointStatus":"Disabled",
                        "endpointMonitorStatus":"Disabled",
                        "target":"MyTargetName2",
                        "weight":1,
                        "priority":2,
                        "endpointLocation":null
                    }
            }
        ]
        ,"trafficViewEnrollmentStatus":"Disabled"
    }
```

}

C# Method to fetch Values from Azure Rest API

```html
private static async Task GetTMPDetailsAsync(string token, string TeamGroupsName, string ServiceName, string SubscriptionName, string SubscriptionGUID, string SQLServerName, string SQLServerAdmin, string SQLServerAdminPasword, string DatabaseName)
        {
            string ResourceType = "Microsoft.Network/trafficmanagerprofiles";
            var httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/")
            };

            // Get Network Profile Name and ResourceGroupName
            string URI = $"/subscriptions/{SubscriptionGUID}/resources?$filter=resourceType%20EQ%20'{ResourceType}'&api-version=2019-05-10";
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(URI).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var HttpsResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dynamic ResourcesList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(HttpsResponse);

            if (ResourcesList.value != null && !ResourcesList.value.Contains("SubscriptionNotFound"))
            {
                foreach (dynamic ResourceName in ResourcesList["value"])
                {
                    string ResourceID = ResourceName.id;
                    string ProfileName = ResourceName.name;
                    string Region = ResourceName.location;
                    string ResourceGroupName = ResourceID.Remove(0, 67);
                    int CharsToRemove = 52 + ProfileName.Length;
                    ResourceGroupName = ResourceGroupName.Remove(ResourceGroupName.Length - CharsToRemove);

                    var TMPhttpClient = new HttpClient
                    {
                        BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/")
                    };

                    // Get EndPoints and Targets
                string TMPURI = $"/subscriptions/{SubscriptionGUID}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroupName}/providers/{ResourceType}/{ProfileName}?api-version=2018-04-01";
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                HttpResponseMessage EndPointResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(TMPURI).ConfigureAwait(false);
                var EndPointsResponse = await EndPointResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                dynamic ProfileList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(EndPointsResponse);

                foreach (dynamic ProfileDetailed in ProfileList)
                {
                    string EndPointName = ProfileDetailed.properties.endpoints.name;
                    string Target = ProfileDetailed.properties.endpoints.properties.target;

                    DateTime RawDate = DateTime.Now;
                    string RefreshedAt = RawDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");

                    Console.WriteLine($"'{TeamGroupsName}', '{ServiceName}', '{SubscriptionName}', '{SubscriptionGUID}', '','', '{ProfileName}', '{Region}',' {EndPointName}', {Target}, '{RefreshedAt}'");
                    //string SQLStatement = ($"INSERT INTO AzureCapacityUsage..TMPDetailed_New" +
                    //                  $" Select '{TeamGroupsName}', '{ServiceName}', '{SubscriptionName}', '{SubscriptionGUID}', '','', '{ProfileName}', '{Region}',' {EndPointName}', {Target}, '{RefreshedAt}'");

                    //SQLConnectionHelper.ExecuteTSQL(SQLServerName, SQLServerAdmin, SQLServerAdminPasword, DatabaseName, SQLStatement);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: It does not seem like you're parsing the `HttpsResponse1` variable - only assigning it to a new variable.

Comment: I just edited the variable with more meaningful names. please take a look now.

Comment: I would model the returned JSON with classes and do a typed parse instead of dynamic. If you don't want to do that, have you stepped through your code with a debugger to analyse the structure?

Comment: Yes I used Debugger. It is failing with error "RuntimeBinderException: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' does not contain a definition for 'properties"

Just to test the format of the resposne, I pasted the response in JSON File and tried to fetch values from it using powershell. It works like a charm. 
I'm just not able to do it in C#. I pasted the Powershell version to fetch values from JSON Http response.

Comment: Your `foreach` does not make sense, it should probably be on `ProfileList.properties.enpoints` since that's the only place you have a list in that JSON...

Comment: One of my senior  Software colleague solved my problem. 
He created a separate class with object collections in it. 
Now I'm able to get what I wanted.  I pasted my final code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
private static async Task GetTMPDetailsAsync(string token, string TeamGroupsName, string ServiceName, string SubscriptionName, string SubscriptionGUID, string SQLServerName, string SQLServerAdmin, string SQLServerAdminPasword, string DatabaseName)
        {
            string ResourceType = "Microsoft.Network/trafficmanagerprofiles";
            var httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/")
            };

            // Get Network Profile Name and ResourceGroupName
            string URI = $"/subscriptions/{SubscriptionGUID}/resources?$filter=resourceType%20EQ%20'{ResourceType}'&api-version=2019-05-10";
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(URI).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var HttpsResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dynamic ResourcesList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(HttpsResponse);

            if (ResourcesList.value != null && !ResourcesList.value.Contains("SubscriptionNotFound"))
            {
                foreach (dynamic ResourceName in ResourcesList["value"])
                {
                    string ResourceID = ResourceName.id;
                    string ProfileName = ResourceName.name;
                    string Region = ResourceName.location;
                    string ResourceGroupName = ResourceID.Remove(0, 67);
                    int CharsToRemove = 52 + ProfileName.Length;
                    ResourceGroupName = ResourceGroupName.Remove(ResourceGroupName.Length - CharsToRemove);

                    var TMPhttpClient = new HttpClient
                    {
                        BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/")
                    };

                    // Get EndPoints and Targets
                    string TMPURI = $"/subscriptions/{SubscriptionGUID}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroupName}/providers/{ResourceType}/{ProfileName}?api-version=2018-04-01";
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                    HttpResponseMessage EndPointResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(TMPURI).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    var endPointsResponse = await EndPointResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    ProfileDetailed profiles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProfileDetailed>(endPointsResponse);

                    foreach (var endpoint in profiles.Properties.Endpoints)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{endpoint}");
                        string endpointName = endpoint.Name;
                        string target = endpoint.EndPointProperties.Target;

                        DateTime RawDate = DateTime.Now;
                        string RefreshedAt = RawDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");

                        Console.WriteLine($"'{TeamGroupsName}', '{ServiceName}', '{SubscriptionName}', '{SubscriptionGUID}', '','', '{ProfileName}', '{endpointName}', {target}, '{RefreshedAt}'");
                        string SQLStatement = ($"INSERT INTO AzureCapacityUsage..TMPDetailed_New" +
                                               $" Select '{TeamGroupsName}', '{ServiceName}', '{SubscriptionName}', '{SubscriptionGUID}', '','', '{ProfileName}', '{endpointName}', '{target}', '{RefreshedAt}'");

                        SQLConnectionHelper.ExecuteTSQL(SQLServerName, SQLServerAdmin, SQLServerAdminPasword, DatabaseName, SQLStatement);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```